# Can an instance creation in fixed block lead to invalid pointers or corrupt memory?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Assume an unsafe method. There is a fixed block that pins an array by the first element, i.e. `fixed (void* p = &array[0])`. In that block, an instance is being created by either a `new` keyword, or by a `Marshal.PtrToStructure`. Am I risking `p` to point to an invalid address? Will this corrupt the memory?

Example:

```
unsafe object ArrayToObject(Byte[] array, Type type)
{
    // Precondition checks on arguments

    fixed (void* p = &array[0])
    {
        return Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(p), type));
    }
}
```

I am facing a rather rare issue with the above implementation, where the resulting object did not match with the data in the array. (The last segment either all 0, or blatantly obvious that it couldn't be that.) This method is also called frequently at times, often less than 1ms apart. Array allocations also happen in such frequency on a *separate thread,* so that also could cause my problem.
I'm also not using the software with such intensity, so I can't really reproduce the issue. Besides, I only seen this issue on .NET 4.0 only so far.

I've recently read a book suggesting to *avoid heap allocations in fixed blocks,* but otherwise have not seen any mention of a risk here, while seen plenty assurance that the object is pinned, and will not be moved. I've also didn't finished the book yet, so not certain if that explains this. (Doesn't explain such thing right away at least.)
Also recently read how GC will move small objects around between the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd generation heaps, and unfortunately `array` is small enough (does not exceed 1,000 elements) so relocation of the array would be possible if not for the fixed block.

Currently I've switched to `GCHandle`, which I'm expecting to resolve this issue, but this bugs me.

Due to backward compatibility, this behavior interests me on .NET 4.0 as well as .NET 4.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `fixed` block, `p` is perfectly well defined, and the `PtrToStructure` call allocates a *new* object **copying data out** from the buffer, so: once `PtrToStructure` has completed, where it came from doesn't matter. As such, there's nothing wrong with this code. However, if you're trying to "allocate" the object inside the existing buffer: that isn't what this code does.

If the type involved is a `struct` with no references (i.e. one that would satisfy the `unmanaged` constraint), there are ways of getting a managed (i.e. not `unsafe`) reference to the data *inside* the existing array, while coercing the type (usually between `byte` and some custom `struct`), for example:

```cs
static ref T Coerce<T>(byte[] array) where T : unmanaged
    => ref MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, T>(array)[0];
```

with usage:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    byte[] data = new byte[16];
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(data));
    ref SomeStruct val = ref Coerce<SomeStruct>(data);
    val.a = 1;
    val.b = 2;
    val.c = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(data));
}

struct SomeStruct
{   // note: structs should usually be "readonly"; this
    // is for convenience of example only
    public int a, b, c;
}
```

Note that this can also work with any arbitrary memory (stack, unmanaged heap, etc) by changing `byte[]` to `Span<byte>` in the `Coerce<T>` signature.

Comment: Sadly, not only I'm working with objects with reference member types (fixed string and byte arrays), but also working with classes, so can't use this. Also, I am trying to retrieve an arbitrary structure from a native memory address, which was copied to an array beforehand (hence the array allocations in the background) so no, I'm not trying to allocate the object inside the array. I'll update the question some time later.

Comment: @AdamL.S. then the key things remain: the access of the pointer only lasts for the duration of `PtrToStructure`, so the code is fine